# Updated Spatial data for Germany on county level

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial

I didn't find updated Spatial data for Germany on county level. I used a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame from [gadm](http://gadm.org/) before, which were perfect until some reforms concerning administrative boundaries. Further, I tried an updated version from [Geodatenzentrum](http://www.geodatenzentrum.de/geodaten/gdz_rahmen.gdz_div?gdz_spr=deu&gdz_akt_zeile=5&gdz_anz_zeile=0&gdz_user_id=0), but I didn't get a complete map of all German counties or had failed to transform UTM 32 data properly.
If anyone has an idea how to get these data it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the openstreetmap administrative areas appropriate?
http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany.html

Comment: The restrictions on commenting mean I don't yet have enough reputation to comment, yet I wanted to try to help @tfr

Comment: Fair enough. Sorry, I didn't realize there were restrictions like that on comments.

Comment: No worries. The policy is a pain in the arse for exactly this reason.